# geany-plugin-debugger missing in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, 18.04, plugins, geany

In older versions of Ubuntu (up to 17.10), there was the package [`geany-plugin-debugger`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=geany-plugin-debugger). Is there a special reason why there is no such package in Ubuntu 18.04? For all other [`geany` plugins](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=geany-plugin-&searchon=names).), there seem to be corresponding packages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason seems to be that webkitgtk-3.0 is deprecated. From changelog:

"Disable webkit-using plugins: markdown, webhelper webkitgtk-3.0 is not to be used as it is deprecated, but the port to webkit2gtk-4.0 isn't ready yet."

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/geany-plugins/1.32+dfsg-3